# Upload de Imagem para diretório Hostinger

Tags: php

Galera estou tentando salvar (upload) uma imagem em um diretório da **Hostinger**, porém não estou conseguindo faze-lo.

Abaixo segue me script PHP.

**Obs.:** A imagem em Base64 está vindo de um app Android.

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "ftp.endereço.server";
$ftp_user = "*****";
$ftp_pass = "*****";
$imageCodificada = $_POST['imageCodificada'];


//DECODIFICAR IMAGEM
$imageDecodificada = base64_decode($imageCodificada);


// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com $ftp_server"); 

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "Conectado! na $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
    file_put_contents(include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public_html/imagens/fotos_func/TESTE.jpg"), imageDecodificada);



} else {
    echo "Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com $ftp_user\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);  
?>
```

Meu Script PHP não dá erro, porém o arquivo não aparece no diretório.

Alguém poderia me ajudar em como fazer isso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem permissões para criar um ficheiro ali?

Comment: Jorge, obrigado pelo retorno. Eu criei um permit para isso. Se fiz corretamente tenho acesso sim, tanto que no meu script o echo sai com "Conectado!"...o problema é que o arquivo não grava.

Answer (score 1):

Aquele “include” parece não fazer sentido:

```
file_put_contents(include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public_html/imagens/fotos_func/TESTE.jpg"), imageDecodificada);
```

Remova-o:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public_html/imagens/fotos_func/TESTE.jpg", imageDecodificada);
```

Ainda assim, precisa fazer o upload pelo FTP. Pois o arquivo físico foi criado localmente. Agora precisa enviá-lo. Mas no seu código não há nenhum comando de envio. Está apenas abrindo e fechando o FTP sem fazer nada.

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado pelo retorno.
Mas você poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso...é que sou novato em dev php e não sei como fazer esse Upload pelo FTP.

Estou quebrando a cabeça mais não estou conseguindo enviar a imagem para um diretório da Hostinger.